# Flask app fails to run when deployed to pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a web app that makes calls to the movie database. Everything runs fine when it's running on localhost. I'm attempting to deploy it on pythonanywhere. I have created a virtual environment and installed all the dependencies. I believe I have edited the WSGI file correctly.

```
import sys
path = '/home/gcmatt/capstone/src'
if path not in sys.path
   sys.path.append(path)
from app import app as application
```

At least from the error messages I get it appears to have found the files.
When I try to load the page it fails to run. It appears that for some reason the code won't import my own functions src.models.search.

```
2018-03-31 15:28:50,341: Error running WSGI application
2018-03-31 15:28:50,349: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
2018-03-31 15:28:50,349:   File 
"/var/www/gcmatt_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 82, in <module>
2018-03-31 15:28:50,349:     from app import app as application  # noqa
2018-03-31 15:28:50,349: 
2018-03-31 15:28:50,349:   File "/home/gcmatt/capstone/src/app.py", 
line 4, in <module>
2018-03-31 15:28:50,350:     from src.models.search import Search
```

Do I need to alter the file structure or file paths in the python code for the app to run? I followed the tutorials on python anywhere and feel that I have set everything up correctly.

This is what my directory structure looks like

```
capstone/
|--.git/
|--src/
   |models/
    |--__init__.py
    |--results.py
    |--search.py
  |--templates
    |--base.html
    |--home.html
    |--noresults.html
    |--search.html
  |--__init__.py
  |--api_file.txt
  |--app.py
  |--requirements.txt
```

Comment: Can you post your directory structure as well

Comment: Maybe you should rename `app.py` by something else, e.g. `myapp.py` because later you are importing the variable `app` which has the same name. I also had `from app import app as application` in my wsgi file and it was leading to issues until I renamed it...

Answer (score 5):

Since you set your `path = '/home/gcmatt/capstone/src'`, the `src` module is not available on `path`. Only `models`, `templates` etc are.

Python is only going to recognize a package if it can see a **subdirectory** with an `__init__.py` in it. It will **not** recognize the current directory as a package, regardless of whether the current directory has `__init__.py` or not.

Try setting `path = '/home/gcmatt/capstone'` and it should be able to detect the package `src`.

Edit here: you may also want to say `from src.app import app as application`

Second edit here: In your `app.py` you should also change your imports to import subpackages instead of `src.[something]`. For instance: `from models.search import Search`. Your WSGI will see the package `src`, and import `src.app` from it. And then `src.app` imports packages relative to itself (i.e. `import models`).

Source: I use PythonAnywhere for a lot of my apps :)

[Here is some further reading on regular Python packages](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages).

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions. Unfortunately, I'm still receiving the same error messages.

Comment: What are the imports you have in app.py?

Comment: `from flask import Flask, render_template, request`
`from wtforms import Form, StringField, validators`
`from src.models.search import Search`

Comment: After making those changes that @GabrielBoorse suggested, are you still seeing the same errors?

Comment: Yes, I'm still experiencing the same errors. It doesn't import src.models.search.